# Connecting two dev orgs

Tags: apex, visualforce, connected-apps

I need to connect to another salesforce org from my dev org and retrieve all the classes of the other org and display the list in a  visualforce page in my dev org. Can someone give some idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can try using ant retrieve for retrieving the code from source and deploying it to destination

Comment: @RCS My task is not to deploy, it's just to fetch the names of all the apex classes of other org and display the list in a visualforce page. My intention is to know how to connect to other org access it's data from this org.

Comment: Then you can use Tooling API's to access the meta-data of other org.

Comment: I'll check on that.

Answer (score 1):

@Surya, You could get all the Apex class information from any org by running a query on ApexClass object after connecting to that org. 
Following are the steps:
 1. Login on into that org using SOAP API. Retrieve the Connection object after successful login. Refer [here for some SOAP API guidance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm)
 Following is the code snippet of logging in onto an org using SOAP API:

`1.Login giving username/pwd

   PartnerSoapSforceCom.Soap con = new PartnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();

   PartnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult

   = con.login('username', 'pwdwithsecuritytoken');`
2.To run a SOQL against this connection object,
String soqlSt = 'Select Name  From User ';
 PartnerSoapSforceCom.QueryResult = con.query(soqlSt);
//Parse this QueryResult to get the values 
3. Following is the query you have to use to get the classes information.

> Select Name,Status, NamespacePrefix,CreatedDate, CreatedById, ApiVersion
>   From ApexClass a`